# Building multiple arrays from a read textfile

Tags: arrays, for-loop, labview

I am trying to build multiple arrays from a read textfile. The read text file comes out as a long column of numbers, and I am trying to split them in groups of three, building arrays until I am done running through the numbers. Here is the block diagram. I know you need a for loop to do this, but figuring out a way to utilize it is giving me lots of trouble.

[image: LV diagram]

Comment: You might want to replace the first two sub routines with the "Read From Spreadsheet File.vi"

Answer (score 2):

You need the Reshape Array primitive. See image.

The attached image is a PNG VI snippet. Drag it out of your browser onto a block diagram to instantiate the code directly. This snippet works with LV 2015 and earlier (as noted in the image in the upper right corner). You can create snippets for future posts by selecting code on the block diagram and choosing "Edit >> Create VI Snippet From Selection". 
[image: Solution]